# JavaScript async/await on non-supported browsers

Tags: javascript, async-await

What is the effect of using `async` / `await` in a browser that does not support it? Are these directives just ignored or will an exception be thrown? If the former, is the effect limited to the script block in which this code is contained, *i.e.* is just that block ignored?

Comment: exceptions will be thrown, the old interpreters dont know the new keywords async / await. They will cause syntax errors. You can Bable.js to transpile your ES7 codebase to ES5 or simliar

Comment: OK thanks.  I just noticed recently that some `async/await` code I was using didn't cause any problems for older browsers (running in an Android environment), but when I moved that code elsewhere, suddenly it was causing problems.  But the reason, I now see, is that the call to a function containing `async/await` was nested inside a `if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)` check... and therefore any browser without `serviceWorker` (and without ES7 support) wasn't seeing the `async/await`... until I moved it outside of that check.